# How to get multiple radio button values in angularjs form?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have questioner form, in their question have multple options. how to get user selected options?

Here is the code?

```
         ...
         <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="question in questionPaper.questions">
              <div>{{question.description}}</div>
              <ul>
                <li ng-repeat="option in question.options">
                  <span>
                <input type="radio" name="option_question_{{question.id}}" ng-model="option.id"/>
                {{option.description}}
              </span>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
         ...
```

How to get option values as

```
{question_paper_id: 1, answers: [{question_id: 1, options_id: 23}, {question_id: 2, options_id: 21}, {..}] }
```

Here is my code in plnkr http://plnkr.co/edit/OTDsUUCiDGYfxJ2AMzFR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you can dynamically add a property when the radio button is selected:

```
<input type="radio" ng-model="question.selected_id" ng-value="option.id"/>

$scope.selected_ids = [];
$scope.submitAnswers = function() {
    angular.forEach($scope.questionPaper.questions, function(question) {
        $scope.selected_ids.push(question.selected_id);
    });
}
```

Take a look at the demo:  http://plnkr.co/edit/QG8XP0jfjyJPY1xaXx6d?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

everything else seems to fine. just replace your script tag for including angular with this

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.22/angular.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Please check the code in plnkr, In the form there is multiple radio button options for each question, How map the answer(user selected radio button option) to respective question?